# How is functional programming beneficial in parallel computations?

Tags: parallel-processing, functional-programming, programming-languages

> It’s interesting to note that there exist functional programming languages, like Scala or Erlang that forbid changing variable values.
> there are areas like parallel computations where this limitation confers certain benefits. Studying such a language (even if you’re not planning to use it soon) is recommended to broaden the mind.

So I started wondering how it's beneficial to parallel computations?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"how it's beneficial to parallel computations?"*

In that neither of code-execution paths ever tries to change any variable, the less it ever changes the value of the variable, so all benefit from a warranty of principally coherent ( as per it's value *(never ever changed)* ), non-colliding processing.

No such thing as a race on read/write coherent-access to a variable (that is by definition never changed).

If nothing else this is *A COOL property* for the <sub>*(by definition safe)*</sub> **`[PARALLEL]`** flow of code-execution paths, isn't it?

Comment: does compiler need to add a thread pool to schedule all functions in a program ?

Comment: or compiler does not need do anything about threading, multiple core CPU will do run application automatically by CPU's natual archecture ?

Comment: @linrongbin for obvious reasons, the compiler phase has no way to know how many cores will a code-execution target platform have, has it? For details one has to dive deeper into the particular functional language compiler design & implementation. There is code-wise documented what hardware-related assumptions & engineering efforts were or were not put into the actual functional language expressed problem transformation and the resulting code-execution planning and scheduling